# Fast and reliable way to find out if a source code file implements an interface

Tags: java, parsing

Given a java source code file, what is a fast and reliable way to find out if it implements a given interface?

A reliable way would be to parse the file into a syntax tree (using e.g. the ASTNode class of eclipse) and look for the right nodes.

A fast way would be to look for lines with "implements", kick out those that are in comments, and relate the interface to an appropriate import statement. I am probably missing some strange other cases here.

What would you do?

Comment: [Reflections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html) API?

Comment: @drgPP - Reflections lib works on classes, though, not on source code...

Comment: I really didn't understand what are you asking. You already answered! o.O

Comment: If you know both types, you can use the instanceof operator

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth misunderstood the meaning of source code..

Comment: @Stultuske - Not on source code...

Comment: Do you need to account for a case when `class A implements AnInterface` and `class B extends A`? Should this hierarchy return `true` for `B` as well? If that's the case, then the safe method is compiling all the classes and using reflection. Looking at the sources alone would require recursively examining any supertype classes' sources.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I didn't see a statement saying he's not allowed to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that parsing a source code file is both, fast and reliable. But "fast" is such a vague notion that it really depends, I guess. I wouldn't expect too much overhead when compared to scanning the source file for occurrences of the words "implements", though -- thus if the latter is fine for you, I'd assume the former should be acceptable too?

The [javax.tools.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) API would be a good entrance point to get started; however, there are also a number of (open source) source code parsers for Java out there.

Also, [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/source_code_analysis_using_java) is an introductory blog post on Oracle's websites.

Answer (score 2):

> What would you do?

I would compile the source code of the class and the interface, load both using `Class.forName()`, and use `Class.isAssignableFrom` to test if the class is a subtype of the interface.

Relatively fast, totally reliable ... assuming that the source code is compilable.

Note that this can all be done at runtime, and if you use a throw-away instance of a properly implemented custom classloader to do the loading, you can avoid polluting your JVM with dubious classes.